# Html bug with block width and scrollbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap and change default width to 1265px. Try resize out window to 1265px. (demo http://markup.website-builder.ru/demonstration/test.html )

In example we have few blocks and when you resize window - the bug appears. A mystic white line on the right of the screen http://take.ms/fOEn2

How could i fix this? Why is it appears?

Overflow-x is bad idea, because everything else will be broken.

Thanks

Comment: it is not a scrollbar http://take.ms/yjqj4

Comment: Could it have anything to do with this - `@media (min-width: 1265px)
.container { width: 1265px;}` ? Don't forget you have extra margins/padding applied under Bootstrap

Comment: Yep, i see this margins and paddings. But how to make this line gone? I tried 100 different combinations but nothing happens..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 30px width difference because you have 15px padding left and right, so that means there are two possible solutions:

```
@media (min-width: 1265px)
.container {
    width: 1235px;
}

@media (min-width: 1295px)
.container {
    width: 1265px;
}
```